# Can I write and play from a audio stream buffer at the same time (in NAudio)?

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, audio-recording, playback, naudio

I have been pointed towards NAudio as possibly allowing me to do this. However, if it cannot, I would appreciate suggestions of libraries that can. I am currently working in C#/WPF, but comfortable calling other C/C++ libraries.

I am receiving a continuous buffer of audio samples (mono). Type: 16-bit signed integer. Rate: 16 kHz.
I will need to hold 1-2 hours of buffer data (230 MB). I want to save this buffer to disk so I can retrieve it later.

Need to be able to play parts of this buffer while still capturing, e.g.:

```
@0s, Buffer.StartRecording()
@30s, handle = Buffer.Play(20,25) //Plays the buffer from 20 - 25 s
@50s, handle1 = Buffer.Play(20,25)
@51s, handle2 = Buffer.Play(20,25) //Playing two parts of the buffer at the same time.
@52s, handle1.Stop() //Buffer1 stops playing after having played for 2 seconds.
```

I should be able to start playing a sound that hasn't finished writing yet:

```
@0s, Buffer.StartRecording()
@25s, handle = Buffer.Play(20,30) //Plays the buffer from 20 - 30 s
@30s, //Buffer has played halfway through (currently, play marker is at 25 s
@35s, //Buffer playing finishes.
```

Need to be able to mask out parts of played-back buffer, e.g.:

```
bufferMaskStep = 1 //seconds
bufferMask = [1, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.1] //the volumes at each time step
Buffer.Play(20, 25, bufferMask, bufferMaskStep)
```

I see that NAudio offers `WaveStream`, but apparently `WaveStream.Write` is not supported. I could manage appending to a byte buffer myself, and copy sections out of it when I want to play them, but I am wondering if there is an out-of-the-box solution.

The gist of what I'm doing is making a loop pedal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NAudio, `BufferedWaveProvider` is designed so you can be reading audio from it (e.g. playing from it) while adding audio into it (e.g. received from a soundcard or over the network).

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing raw audio data to the disk as a long-term buffer, then you are going to have to handle it yourself.

You have two basic options, depending on how you want to isolate the read and write operations: create a single `FileStream` object with read/write access to the file, or create multiple `FileStream` objects - one for writing, and however many you need for reading.

The first option is the simplest.  When you create your `FileStream` object, make sure it has ReadWrite access:

```
FileStream datafile = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

You can use that `Stream` to append data to the file by setting the `Position` to the end of the file before calling `Write`.  Similarly to read data from a position in the file you set the `Position` to the offset into the file of the data you want to read, then call `Read`.

The other option is a bit more difficult, but gives you a certain amount of separation between the read and write operations.  When you create each `FileStream` object you need to specify the `FileShare` option you need to allow multiple views of the same file.

In this scenario you would create a write Stream with the following options:

```
FileStream dataWriter = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
```

When you want to read from the file create a new `FileStream` with read access like so:

```
FileStream dataReader = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

---

Storing the data is the (relatively) simple part.  The fun part is getting the data in and out of the store.

I will update this answer shortly with some more details.  Let me play with it for a while.

Comment: I understand how to write and read from a continuous buffer - I have done this for other projects. What I'm looking for is something that can do this for sound. Especially if I can start playing a sound buffer that I'm still adding to.